# Chrome extension won't launch without a page refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My chrome extension with manifest v3 won't launch without a page refresh or navigate from another site.

I specified the URLs I needed in manifest.json, but when I navigate from other sections of the site, for example, https://vk.com/feed, the extension won't start. What can I do to make the extension add the content I need to the vk.com/target page and stop working when moving to other sections of the site without refresh? How can I track page url changes? Thank you in advance

Here's my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Target",
    "description": "Target Features",
    "version": "1.0",

    "action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
  
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "https://vk.com/target"
        ],
        "js": ["script.js"]
      }
    ],

    "permissions": [
      "storage"
    ]
  }
```

Here's my script.js

```
// Create Square block
const target_block = document.createElement('div');
target_block.style.width = '100px';
target_block.style.height = '100px';
target_block.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
target_block.style.position = 'fixed';
target_block.style.top = '50%';
target_block.style.left = '50%';
target_block.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';

document.body.appendChild(target_block);
```

Comment: Is it working in the first place?
Change "`https://vk.com/target`" to "`https://vk.com/target/*`" or it should not work.

Comment: This site is a SPA so the page remains the same and the URL in the address bar is "faked". Replace `target` with `*` in manifest.json, then add `navigation.onnavigate = check; check();` in script.js where check is your function that checks location.href and shows/hides the element accordingly.